# Using "image" type drop down box with vbscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I am automating a website, and I was doing well until I came across a drop down box that at the time I thought was a "submit" type. But when I ran my script it did not select anything in the box. It was at this point that I saw that it was actually an "image" type.

My question is: Can I select and fill this "image" type with VBscript, without JavaScript, or must I learn JavaScript before I can continue?

I have seen mentions of arrays with drop down boxes, but they seem to be for changing a selection in the drop down list, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days of looks through web searches, Trail and Error, and few choice words I posted to this forum and three hours later my question was answered by myself.

```
ie.Document.getElementsByName("").Item(0).click
```

This allowed me to click the open the drop down list.